# codeigniter activerecord where clause issue with own clauses manually

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm not sure it's right or wrong but I want to use below `where` clauses. I'm following [Codeigniter](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) manual (chapter **Active Record Class**, section **$this->db->where();**, point **4) Custom string**).

1. `$condition = uid = '4' AND  id = '1';`
2. My Controller

```
$fields = "id";
$condition = "";
if($condition) { 
  $condition.=" AND ";
}
if($json_decoded->userId) { 
  if($condition) { 
    $condition.=" AND ";
  }
  $condition.=" uid = '".$json_decoded->userId."'";
}
if($json_decoded->listId) { 
  if($condition) { 
    $condition.=" AND ";
  }
  $condition.=" id = '".$json_decoded->listId."'";
}
 $checkExist = $this->mdl_details->getDetailByIdandUid($fields,$condition);
```

3. My Models function

```
$this->db->select($fields);

$this->db->from(TBL_DETAILS);

if(!empty($condition)) { 
  $this->db->where($condition);
}

$query = $this->db->get()->row();
echo $this->db->last_query(); die;
return $query;
```

It shows me error as bellow

> Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column ' uid = '4' AND id = '1'' in 'where clause'
>
> SELECT `id` FROM (`guide`) WHERE ` uid = '4' AND id = '1'

How can I get rid of this backtick (`) character in the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass 'FALSE' as third parameter in $this->db->where(), then codeigniter will not add backticks.

```
$this->db->where('MATCH (field) AGAINST ("value")', NULL, FALSE);
```

In your case

```
$this->db->where($condition, NULL, FALSE);
```

Comment: @Syam can you please kindly tell me what does this do MATCH (field) AGAINST ("value")...?

Comment: It means you can write your own where clauses. For example:  $this->db->where("uid = '4' AND id = '1'", NULL, FALSE);  , where uid is 'field' and '4' is the value